# Google Natural Language API with Java - setLanguage

Tags: java, google-language-api

I am using the Google Natural Language API to analyze entities from different texts. Is there a way to change the language of the input text to, for example english, as it is the case with the AlchemyAPI with

```
service.setLanguage (LanguageSelection.ENGLISH);
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You specify the language via the relevant ISO or BCP-47 tag in the [`Document`](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/reference/rest/v1beta1/documents#Document) part of the request. So for example:

```
Document document = Document.newBuilder()
    .setLanguage("en")
    .set... // Call other setters
    .build();
```